# how to make Communication via USB (phone to PC)?

Tags: java, android, usb, file-transfer

I have a request where i want to communicate my phone with the windows PC via USB. i have searched at many places but everybody finds problem when it comes to java. 
can anybody guide me on this i am new to HW communication. we will be implementing this think most probably on android mobile version 2.2 (API Level 8).
mobile implementation is next phase in this but first thing required is how can we implement this communication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to develop your own driver application you better read [USB complete](http://www.lvr.com/usbc.htm) first.
A Java USB library like [JUSB library](http://jusb.sourceforge.net/) will help you on the USB communication.